# Trying to import Email.js CDN with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Cant find a concrete answer on how to import this correctly.
Email js is installed via NPM 
I try to import it with HEAD tag

```
<Head>
            <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("YOUR_USER_ID");
   })();
</script></Head>
```

And i keep getting emailjs is undefined. No worries i will not be using next js again this was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from their npm package documentation. When using NextJS, you should generally use `import` or `require`

```
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

const templateParams = {
    name: 'James',
    notes: 'Check this out!'
};

emailjs.send('<YOUR SERVICE ID>','<YOUR TEMPLATE ID>', templateParams, '<YOUR USER ID>')
    .then((response) => {
       console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
    }, (err) => {
       console.log('FAILED...', err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks can you send me a link to the documentation?

Comment: the npm docs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs-com please accept the answer if it worked